# separate list dictonary into columns and values

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame which contains a column "ExtData" with values `[{"key":"title","value":"activation"},{"key":"remarks","value":"activation"}]`

I have to separate this data and create a new data frame with "title" and "remarks" column name and their value "activation" i.e "key" is column name and their "value" as value.

I have data frame like this

```
partner               ExtData
xyz          [{"key":"title","value":"activation"}, {"key":"remarks","value":"activation"}]
abc          [{"key":"title","value":"activation"}, {"key":"remarks","value":"activation"}]
```

I need output as new data frame with

```
**partner**   **title**      **remarks**
xyz           activation     activation
abc           activation     activation
```

using pandas and python.

---

[image]

Comment: Please, provide reproducible example

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijYIj.png

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution, using [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method:

```
def separate_extdata(row):
    for d in row['ExtData']:
            row[d['key']] = d['value']
    return row.drop('ExtData')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
      ('xyz', [{"key": "title", "value": "activation"},
               {"key":"remarks","value":"activation"}]), 
      ('abc', [{"key":"title","value":"activation"}, 
               {"key":"remarks","value":"activation"}])], 
    columns=['partner', 'ExtData']
)
df.apply(separate_extdata, axis=1)
#   partner       title     remarks
# 0     xyz  activation  activation
# 1     abc  activation  activation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = pandas.Dataframe()
new_index = 0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if 'key' in row['ExtData']:
       k = row['ExtData']['key']
       v = row['ExtData']['value']
       new_df.loc[new_index, k] = v
       new_index+=1
```

Comment: It wasn't clear if you wanted to keep this values in the same row of the new dataframe or in different rows, I presumed the latter

Comment: Grigoriy's answer may be more appropriate then